# How can I apply an alpha mask image in TransLoadIt?

Tags: image-masking, transloadit

Using ImageMagick on the command line I can use the composite and compose options to use one image to replace the alpha mask of another image.  Is this possible using transloadit ?  I see an option to add a watermark but nothing related to replacing the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently not possible. I'm a Transloadit cofounder though and if you can email us about your usecase, timeframe, and expected volume, we might be able to implement this for you.